# Responsive full-screen navigation with elements/icons

Tags: html, css, navigation, icons, alignment

I'm trying to make this full-screen responsive navigation.

[what I try to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ktg3y.png)

However, when I try to code it I can't get it done for some reason. I work with Bootstrap 4 and I tried working with rows/columns, but that didn't work. My basis looks like this right now.

[What I have right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNjxV.png)

1. One problem is that I don't know how to get the icons aligned next to each other on the same line as the contact/faq.
2. Besides that I would like to make the navigation responsive, so I want to make sure that the ratio of the elements are pretty much the same on every screen, but how to do this?

This is my HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <title>Our Story</title> 
    </head>

    <header class="container-fluid fixed-top p-0">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light">
            <button class="navbar-toggler align-items-center" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navDropdownMenu" aria-controls="navbarDropdownToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand mx-auto p-0" href="index.html">FORRESTR</a>

            <button class="shoppingCart navbar-toggler" type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navDropdownMenu">
                <div class="navbarCollapse">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="index.html">Products</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="ourstory.html">Our Story</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="partners.html">Partners</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="process.html">Process</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link small1" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a>
                        <a class="nav-item nav-link small2" href="faq.html">FAQ</a>
                        <div class="img-fluid navIcons">
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/theforrestr/">
                                <img src="images/instagram.svg" alt="facebookIcon">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="img-fluid navIcons">
                            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/theforrestr/">
                                <img src="images/facebook.svg" alt="facebookIcon">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main>
        <picture>
            <img class="img-fluid headerImg mt-5 mb-5" src="images/jungle.jpg">
        </picture>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col d-flex mb-3 align-items-center">
                    <h1 class="m-0 ml-5" style="flex-grow: 1;">Our Story</h1>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="container mb-5 p-0">
                <div class="row d-flex p">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                        <p class="mb-0 px-3"><em>“The Amazon hasn't stopped burning. There were 19,925 fire outbreaks last month, and 'more fires' are in the future.”<br></em>The headline on October 18th 2019 in USA Today.<br><br><em>“As fires devastate the Brazilian Amazon rainforest, much of the world has been outraged, arguing the loss will accelerate climate change. French President Emmanuel Macron harshly criticized Brazilian President Jair Bolsonaro for encouraging deforestation. Meanwhile, similarly vast forest fires in Indonesia and Malaysia receive far less attention. In both parts of the world, forest fires usually start as controlled burns set by farmers or plantation companies wanting to clear land for agriculture: soybeans, corn or cattle ranching in the Amazon, and palm oil in Southeast Asia.”</em><br>Article in The Washington Post on October 14th 2019.<br><br>Forests are on fire. The world is on fire. Our future and the future of our children is smoldering. Now is the time that we have to act. Together.Forestr wants to support people that care about their future and the future of their loved ones. We want to bring back the beautiful colours in nature. But for that we need your help!</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="d-sm-block d-md-none" style="height: 16px; background-color: transparent; width: 100%; visibility: hidden;"></div>

                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 d-flex quote d-sm-block d-md-none">
                        <p class="quote text-center" style="overflow-x: hidden;">“I love the forest. It is the place where you hear yourself better.”<br>- Fahadh Faasil</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="d-sm-block d-md-none" style="height: 16px; background-color: transparent; width: 100%; visibility: hidden;"></div>

                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                        <p class="mb-0 px-3">Forestr is a clothing brand that produces T-shirts with colourful illustrations on them. We use colourful illustrations because we like to see things from the bright side of life. These illustrations consist of forest animals in unnatural and sometimes weird scenes. The goal is that people wonder why the animals are in that scene and not in their natural habitat. When people think about it they come to the conclusion that their natural habitat is being destroyed by fire.<br><br>By buying Forestr T-shirts you help the forester to save the forests and rebuild destroyed and burned-down forests. Our products are eco-friendly from T-shirt to packaging and we try to invest as much money as possible in rebuilding the forest. Buy our beautiful product and help us bring colours back to life and animals back to their natural habitat.<br><br>Thank you,
                        </p>
                        <div class="w-100 text-center">
                            <img class="img-fluid mt-4 w-75" src="images/Signature-01.svg" alt="ForestrSignature">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </main>

    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <div class="row flex-md-row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                        <li><a class="mx-3" href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
                        <li><a class="mx-3" href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                        <li><a class="mx-3" href="#">Return Policy</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="d-sm-block d-md-none" style="height: 10px; background-color: white; width: 100px; visibility: hidden;"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
                        <li><a class="mx-3" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
                        <li><a class="mx-3" href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </ul>
            <a href="https://www.instagram.com/theforrestr/">
                <div class="icons mx-3 float-right">
                    <img src="images/instagram.svg" alt="instagramIcon">
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="https://www.facebook.com/theforrestr/">
                <div class="icons float-right">
                    <img src="images/facebook.svg" alt="facebookIcon">
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </footer>
</html>
```

This is my CSS code:

```css
.nav-item{
    font-size: 300%;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 0.03%;
}

.nav-item.small1{
    font-size: 100% !important;
    font-size: 150%;
    padding: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-item.small2{
    font-size: 100% !important;
    font-size: 150%;
    padding: 0px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.navIcons{
    width: 20%;
}
```

Can anyone please help me and tell me what to do? :)

Comment: Try creating a codepen where we can see your HTML and CSS look like the screenshot you provided.

Comment: You can use [Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) to detect the screen size & then have different defined spacings / sizings / etc for each instance. This will help you maintain sizings in between Phone / Desktop / Tablet. You will need to go ahead and make the design correct first. You could look into [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to get the items behaving themselves as stacked rows though!